# SSH to remote server in github actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, github-actions, continuous-deployment

This is what I'm trying to use to connect to remote EC2 instance

```
    - uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
    with:
      host: ip-addr.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
      username: ubuntu
      key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
```

and I'm geting following error:

```
ssh.ParsePrivateKey: ssh: no key found
```

SSH_KEY is a content of .pem file I downloaded from AWS.

content of SSH_KEY secret:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpgIBAAKCAQEA4o8RUZqxYV9+hKtHMmc+s0Y2iwjrtBVI/JmWcsjKQ8
...
glro9iN3kTBl6i3y4Yy4gpDnh0/xcVlZuXOVew7uEyPtA1yrTW1z9kbu
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----%
```

when I try to echo ssh key I'm using it just displays some *** 
Below output from github action:

```
Run echo $SSH_KEY
  echo $SSH_KEY
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    SSH_KEY: ***
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
```

Comment: in `key` you need to place the private key to the public key `.pub` you added to ubuntu's `authorized_keys` file `(/home/users/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys)`

Comment: I thought that I need to use .pem file that I download from aws exactly same way I use to connect to this remote server from local machine(?)

Comment: from my local machine I connect to this EC2 instance like that:
 ssh -i "some-file.pem" ubuntu@ip-addr.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
and "some-file.pem" is file I downloaded from  AWS

Comment: What are the first and last lines of the **pem** file that you are using? Add that to your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley ok I added it

Comment: You are using the correct key format. Echo **${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}** in a step and verify that the value is what you expect.

Comment: ok, I updated my post

Answer (score 5):

Copy the entire content of cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa. Starting from and including the comment section -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- ....... to -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----.

Source:

- https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action/issues/6#issuecomment-922368411

Answer (score 1):

See [`action.yml`](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action/blob/master/action.yml). There's a `debug` mode, which eventually may equal the `ssh -vvv` switch:

```
debug:
  description: 'enable debug mode'
  default: false
```

Just read for yourself:

- [Using SSH to Log In to a Linux Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-ssh.html)
- [Security hardening for GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions)

---

There's even a [SSH key install](https://github.com/shimataro/ssh-key-action) action - but usually it's better to provision keys dynamically.
Which generally means, to provision the key, perform the task, let the key expire soon.

Answer (score 1):

```
name: Deploy On server

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: executing remote ssh commands using password
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.7
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          port: 22
          script_stop: true
          script: ls -all
```

Here as we have used secrets

```
Go to Repository -> Setting -> Secrets and variables -> Action
```

[image: Access Respostory secret]

Add Repository Secret

[image: Addd repository secret]

Create a Secret for your key with their values
HOST
USERNAME
SSH_KEY